# How do I find out what objects I can query with WQL?

Tags: wmi, wql

I want to use WQL to get information about IIS worker processes, plus just about everything in Resource Manager -- disk usage, memory usage, CPU usage, and network usage.

Where can I find a list of all the object names so I can write my queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest use tool like WMIExplorer.

Than translate that query into your prefered language.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186130(v=vs.80).aspx